# NestJS Module that can be instantiated multiple times, how to handle provider token collision?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a module that I want to import multiple times, without having the providers collide between the separate module instances.

Given these interfaces:

```
export enum AccessMode {
  Online = 'online',
  Offline = 'offline',
}

export interface ShopifyAuthModuleOptions {
  basePath?: string;
}
```

I have created the following dynamic module `ShopifyAuthModule`:

```
@Module({})
export class ShopifyAuthModule {
  static forRoot(
    accessMode: AccessMode,
    options: ShopifyAuthModuleOptions,
  ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ShopifyAuthModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: getShopifyAuthProviderToken(accessMode), useValue: options },
      ],
    };
  }

  static forRootAsync(
    accessMode: AccessMode,
    options: ShopifyAuthModuleAsyncOptions,
  ): Promise<DynamicModule> | DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ShopifyAuthModule,
      imports: options.imports || [],
      providers: [
        ...(options.providers || []),
        ...createShopifyAuthAsyncOptionsProviders(options, accessMode),
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

I need to be able to provide this module's options. So I tried making the options provider token dynamic by checking the access mode that is provided to `forRoot` and `forRootAsync`:

```
export const SHOPIFY_AUTH_ONLINE = 'SHOPIFY_AUTH_ONLINE';
export const SHOPIFY_AUTH_OFFLINE = 'SHOPIFY_AUTH_OFFLINE';

export const getShopifyAuthProviderToken = (accessMode: AccessMode) => {
  return accessMode !== AccessMode.Offline
    ? SHOPIFY_AUTH_ONLINE
    : SHOPIFY_AUTH_OFFLINE;
};
```

This way, I can instantiate the module twice without having the options provider collide under the same provider token.

But I would like to fetch these options in my Guard and Exception filter. The problem is, how do I know in which instance I'm in? How do I know if I should fetch the `AcccessMode.Online` option or the `AccessMode.Offline` option?

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class ShopifyAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    @Inject(getShopifyAuthProviderToken(????)) private options: ShopifyAuthModuleOptions
  ) {
    // how do I know which AccessMode i'm in? I want to fetch the correct options
    // for the AccessMode that was provided to this module instance.
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure if you realise that this is a question regarding NestJS. You create a module by calling `ShopifyAuthModule.forRoot()` and you receive an instance of `DynamicModule`. If I call `ShopifyAuthModule.forRoot()` again, I receive a new instance of `DynamicModule`.

Comment: Saw the tag, but didn't know about the feature.